# react ,creating a project issue (npx create-react-app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

npm version = 6.14.4

node version = v12.16.2

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...79WvYfkfE4XCeqsdvhNxl'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\divya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-26T11_35_57_318Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting firstproj/ from C:\Users\divya\React
Done.

Comment: There might be an internet issue. Check out this question. [create-react-app-npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923733/create-react-app-npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near)

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the issue is from npm and non of us has done anything wrong.

try this : `npm install -g --force create-react-app`

if did not work,still we can use Yarn to start a new react project while they solve it, follow the steps:

`step 1: yarn init -y`

step 2: Insert this to `package.json`

```
"resolutions": {
    "is-promise": "2.1.0",
    "run-async/is-promise": "2.1.0"
  }
```

step 3: `yarn add --dev create-react-app`

step 4: `yarn create-react-app ../my-app`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing almost same type of problem. But then tried

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

in power shell with admin privilege which seemed to do the trick.

Also you’ll need to have Node >= 8.10, yarn >= 0.25+ on your machine as the official doc suggests. Hope this helps.