# create-react-app : npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....'

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, npm, npx

#### Describe the bug

`npx create-react-app my-app` doesn't work for me 
i tried `npm cache clean --force` but i get the same error again and again

#### Steps to reproduce

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. npm / `npx create-react-app front`

```
npm init react-app front
npx: installed 98 in 37.068s

Creating a new React app in /home/h4kst3r/Desktop/APIs/restaurant-API/front.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...zAJNgZjZUkJ08ybAxwNnR'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/h4kst3r/.npm/_logs/2020-05-20T20_47_49_189Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting front/ from /home/h4kst3r/Desktop/APIs/restaurant-API
Done.
```

#### System:

OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: which npm version you are using ?

Comment: @FarhaniWalid 6.12.0

Comment: try to reinstall them from scratch and see if it will fix the problem, basically the error that you are getting is raised by one of those packages, alternately this may be caused by the permissions that you have, try first sudo npx create-react-app front

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its happened because of slow internet . So wait till ur internet connection is normal. Or install all dependencies one by one
.

Comment: Seriously, it's correct answer..... I thought it's wrong actually it's solved the problem.....

Comment: Exactly how fast an Internet connection should be for this error not to happen?

Answer (score 2):

If `npx create-react-app my-app` command not working and throws an error like: `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...zAJNgZjZUkJ08ybAxwNnR'`, Just check your npm version:

```
npm --version 
npm -v
```

and if required update it:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

First check for `npm version` by running the following command `npm --version`. if you have an npm version then try instally `npx` globally with the help of `npm i -g npx`. if `npm` and `ngx` are installed properlly then this will work .

Comment: npm npx are both installed!

Comment: sometimes their will be some packages missing thats the reason.

Comment: This helped but I had to also run `npm cache clean --force` after `npm i -g npx`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm i -g npx --force` worked for me.

Comment: Kindly add descriptive answer so other people can understand it's usage and if possible please add any side effect of command.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two things that can be at fault.

1. Poor internet connection.
2. outdated npm version.

update your npm and seek a strong internet connection.